# Not able to tag photos on facebook using the android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, photo-tagging

I am using the following code (from sdk examples "Hackbook") to add a tag to a photo after uploading it.

```
json = Util.parseJson(response);
photo_id = json.getString("id");
String relativePath = photo_id + "/tags/" + Utility.userUID;
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("x", "25");
params.putString("y", "25");
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(relativePath, params, "POST", new TagPhotoRequestListener(),                                null);
```

However, I sometimes (not always) receive the the response from facebook as "false" instead of "true". Is there a specific reason for this?

Additionally, is there a way to tag the photo while uploading it, instead of making an additional call?